# Acquire failover system control

Tags: java, linux, failover

Dude, we have got two linux servers, which one of them is principal(main) and the another one is the agent.
Let's say the main server address is `1.1.1.1` and the agent is `2.2.2.2`. For any reason(power, etc.) the main server would gets crashed.
Currently I monitor the main server by keeping a connection live between agent and main server.
I can identify and understand when the main server goes off.

The problem is I want to acquire the main ip address(`1.1.1.1`) by agent system to track and keep the clients requests, or redirect the client requests to another node.
Now how may I do this? both applications(servers) for agent and main servers are written by Java.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: if you can keep the connection between the two server means both are aware of each others IP. Am i reading it incorrectly?

Comment: Let say I get an exception in agent system when main server goes off, now I want to get the main server ip and response to the clients while I'm trying to start up the main server again. @Shail016

Comment: For complete outage (i.e. crash) of the main server you can use [UCARP](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/ucarp). However, if you want to monitor specific services and switch the IP address based on whether the service is OK or not, you need to use something more complex like [Heartbeat and Pacemaker](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page). Also, what about the storage? Do you plan to replicate data between the two machines?

Comment: @user3584460 I have taken care about the data storage, data is mirrored to some nodes of course. currently I can identify the main server failover, all I want is response the clients by either agent or another mirrors while i'm trying to start up the server again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an ethernet alias as eth0:1 or something on the interface where 2.2.2.2 (note: with these IP addresses you are borked because they are on different subnets, but since they are obviously bogus IP's I'll assume both machines are on the same subnet) is. E.g. if 2.2.2.2 is on eth0, create eth0:1 with IP address 1.1.1.1.  Don't configure it to start (ONBOOT=no with RHEL initscripts).  When main is down, do `ifup eth0:1`

However, the "correct" answer is to use a HA stack - there are billions to choose from, and rolling your own will be vastly inferior.

Comment: Thanks dude, many thanks, so as user3584460 mentioned in comments, I Think UCARP can give a hand of course. but your solution looks better for me.